# In Android Studio, how do I change the background color of the left-hand gutter?

Tags: android-studio, colors, settings, preferences

In Android Studio (version 2.0), the background color of the left-hand gutter is the same background color as my editor. This causes me to erroneously think that my indentions are off.

If I could simply change the background color of the gutter, it will look like a separate area to my eyes, and I won't stop second-guessing the indent levels.

But I can't find the setting (not surprising--there are thousands of settings!).  And as you can see, I only turn line-numbers on while debugging.

In my current settings, you can see how difficult it is to tell the gutter apart from the editor:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Finally found it!

Open up the Preferences according to your Operating System.

Editor -> Colors & Fonts -> General -> Gutter -> Background.  Check the background box on the far right, then click on the rectangle to the right of the checkbox.  A color picker will pop up, allowing you to change the background color of the gutter.
[image]